# How to Create CustomEndpoint which called some groovy script method , and return the xml as response

Tags: apache-camel

How to Create CustomEndpoint which will internally call some groovy script method , and return the xml as response

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps given in the official pages -

http://camel.apache.org/creating-a-new-camel-component.html

http://camel.apache.org/writing-components.html

Comment: Am new to the Apache-camel, and i got this link but am not sure how can we create endpoint, i had tried the producer approach by extending the DefaultEndPoint class which give 3 methods for overriding, am not sure about how to write the createProduce implementaion and how i plugin this end point as my source, any sample example will help me more

Comment: See the source code for all the 100+ components as they are examples how to write components. Also you can check Camel in Action book chapter 11.

Comment: Here is something that gives a basic outline - http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-custom-camel  Hopefully it helps you understand the flow.